# How to get column contains particular options and value in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this

table name: attribute_table

```
id  option_name_1 option_value_1 option_name_2 option_value_2
 1     color         Red            size        10
 2     color         Blue           size        10
 3     size          12
 4     size          14
 5     size          16             color       yellow 
 6     size          18             color       yellow
```

The result should be

```
size contains: 10, 12, 14, 16, 18

color contains: Red, Blue, yellow
```

And my query is

**For size:**

```
SELECT CASE WHEN option_value_2='' THEN 
option_value_1 ELSE option_value_2 END AS optValue 
FROM option_value_2 WHERE 
(option_name_1='size' OR option_name_2='size' ) GROUP BY `optValue`
```

**For color:**

```
SELECT CASE WHEN option_value_2='' THEN 
option_value_1 ELSE option_value_2 END AS optValue 
FROM option_value_2 WHERE 
(option_name_1='size' OR option_name_2='size' ) GROUP BY `optValue`
```

But I am not getting the correct value?

Is there any way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E.g.:

```
SELECT option_name
     , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT option_value ORDER BY CASE WHEN option_name IN('size') THEN option_value + 0 ELSE LENGTH(option_value) END) option_values
  FROM
     ( SELECT id,option_name_1 option_name,option_value_1 option_value FROM attribute_table
       UNION
       SELECT id,option_name_2,option_value_2 FROM attribute_table
     ) x
 WHERE option_name IS NOT NULL
 GROUP 
    BY option_name;
```

Comment: Thanks, This is awesome. Can I get count of rows of option_values?

Comment: Yes. That seems rather straightfoward.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for size:

```
   select distinct option_value_1 from attribute_table where option_name_1 = 'size' 
UNION ALL 
select distinct option_value_2 from attribute_table where option_name_2 = 'size';
```

Similarly you can do it for color.

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct query for size would be:

```
SELECT distinct coalesce(option_value_1, option_value_2) AS optValue 
FROM attribute_table WHERE 
coalesce(option_name_1,option_name_2) ='size'
```

This can be done as well for color.